# Using dispatch_async with self

Tags: grand-central-dispatch, swift

I have run into this problem a few times while porting Objective-C code to Swift. Say I have the following code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.hostViewController?.view.addSubview(self.commandField)
}
```

This will result in an error, underlining the entire `dispatch_async` call, offering:

```
Could not find member 'addSubview'
```

I assume this is an error that has not yet been properly implemented because if I put the `addSubview` call outside the `dispatch_async` block, the project builds fine. Initially I assumed it may have something to do with capturing `self` in the block. However, inserting `[unowned self] in` results in the same error, as does `[weak self] in` (after the appropriate `!` unwrap operators have been inserted).

How can I get `dispatch_async` blocks to work in Swift that need to capture `self`?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You should condition spinning off this action on the non-nullity, not test for it after you've already initiated it:

```
if let hostView = self.hostViewController?.view {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
         hostView.addSubview(self.commandField)
    }
} else {
    // handle nil hostView 
}
```

You should never unwrap an optional outside of an `if let`, or testing it first.  Doing this should also resolve yer weak self issue.

Comment: Ah that works, thanks! So is the compiler complaining that it can't deterministically unwrap `hostController?` inside the block? Or is there something else going on here?

Comment: It's because the expression `self.hostViewController?.view` returns an object of type `NSView?`, *not* `NSView`.  Optional chains always have to be checked and the result either has to be letted or forced.

Answer (score 13):

The `dispatch_async` syntax has changed with Swift 3:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { 
    hostView.addSubview(self.commandField)
}
```